# Configuring language analyzer global for whole index

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to configure the german language analyizer global for a whole index (or bether for all indizes)?

Can I do this without changing the queries?

Comment: Yes you can customize the built-in language analyzers per index or even globally https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.3/analysis-lang-analyzer.html

Comment: If you are talking about using it as the default analyzer you should customize the standard analyzer